# RDP using python

Tags: python, remote-desktop, rdp

I want to create a Python script that allows me to connect to a Remote Machine via an RDP connection. I would really like to know if there are certain APIs in python I can exploit.

Comment: What do you mean by "allows me to connect Remote Machine via an RPD"? You just want to run mstsc.exe with certain connection setting or what?

Answer (score 3):

Not any I know, however you might be able to write a cython wrapper around [libxrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/), which contains library functions for an rdp client. However the library is sparsely documented. There is also FreeRDP (which I don't know), but I'm not sure it's a much better alternative.